# Double border issues with opaque html border

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm having an issue with opaque borders being drawn over each other causing the alpha to be double what it should be.

It appears only to effect the first `n-1` elements — the last child renders fine.

**Codepen example:** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vEyeBG?editors=110

HTML:

```
<h2>Prices</h2>

<table class="prices">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Bananas</td>
      <td>$1/lb</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Oranges</td>
      <td>$4/lb</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Peaches</td>
      <td>$2/lb</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Carrots</td>
      <td>$1/lb</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lettuce</td>
      <td>50¢/head</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Broccoli</td>
      <td>$1/head</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background:#000;
  color:#fff;
  font-weight:bold;
  padding:50px;
}

.prices {
    width: 400px;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-top: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,.2);
}

.prices tbody tr:first-child td {
  padding-top: 12px;
}

.prices tbody tr:last-child td {
            padding-bottom: 12px;
            border-bottom : 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,.2);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it appears to be the `border-collapse: collapse;` property. Remove that and add `border-spacing: 0;` instead

```
.prices {
  width: 400px;
  border-spacing: 0; <-----------
  border-top: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,.2);
}
```

[**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gbLGOg)

Comment: This is definitely it! Turns out my reset.css was already adding the border-collapse for me, which is why I was scratching my head in the first place. Thanks.

Comment: ah yeah resets are nice but sometimes they can cause trouble adding/removing things you dont want. Glad to help